# Ubuntu 14.10 : Qt5 assistant not found

Tags: repository, deb, qt

I am working on a system running Ubuntu 14.10 in which I have started programming on Qt5.

Before for few months when I was working on Qt, I found that that QT-assistant tool really comes in handy. I checked the directory `/usr/share/qt5/`, and I was able to find all the .qch file there which are required by *qt-assistant*.

The problem is I am unable to find the *qt-assistant* program online, the link or a PPA repository or something to install it for qt5. If anyone knows how to install *qt5-assistant* on Ubuntu 14.10, kindly let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QT assistant is packaged as part of qttools5-dev-tools, you will also want qt5-doc for the QT5 SDK documentation.

To install run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-doc qttools5-dev-tools
```

To launch you can run this command from a terminal:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/assistant
```

You may want to create a desktop file to make it launchable from the desktop or menu tool, either in `/usr/share/applications` for any user to be able to use it (you will need administrator permissions) or to `~/.local/share/applications`

I created one called assistant-qt5.desktop with the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Qt;Development;Documentation;
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/assistant
Name=Qt 5 Assistant
GenericName=Document Browser
X-KDE-StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```